# Losing column data when going from dynamic frame to a spark dataframe and then back in AWS Glue

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm converting a glue dynamic frame to a spark dataframe to do some etl.  The Dynamic frame has all the data when I run the toDF command.  The etl runs successfully, but when I convert back using fromDF, I find two of my columns have lost all of their data. These two columns are ones I added through joins several steps before.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Here's the section I lose the data in-

```py
prep_for_df = applymapping4.coalesce(1)

df = prep_for_df.toDF()

mean_age = df.select(mean(df['age'])).collect()

null_age = mean_age[0][0]

df2 = df.na.fill(null_age,['age'])

dyframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df2, glueContext, "dyframe")
```

UPDATE- it was the data type I had set for those two columns that caused the issue. Once I changed them, everything worked as expected.

Comment: What data types caused this issue? Precisely, what was the inferred data type for those columns in a dynamic frame, and pyspark dataframe?

Comment: I have this issue also, in the reverse direction -- spark df full of data, but all data is gone when converting to glue dynamic df. Everything is a string for simplicity, and the schema conversion in glue ddf looks fine, everything is a StringType(). Not sure what's causing this at all.